# Show navigation drawer opened

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, gravity, drawerlayout

I have been looking how to show the navigation drawer opened. I have seen that using Gravity.LEFT makes the animation but I want to show it completely displayed without animation.

This is what makes the animation.

```
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

¿How can I show the DrawerLayout displayed without animation?

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome [library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) to implement the NavigationDrawer in your apps developed by Mike Penz.

Comment: Thank you but I have all working good and the only problem I have is that i don't know how to show it completely displayed, and I think there will be a solution using the android fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line.

```
((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that line of code does the same effect that Gravity.Left. I'm using it in onResume() method and when the user returns to my application. The navigation drawer is animated and displayed.